# Setting char[] inside c struct from swift

Tags: swift

The char[10] inside a C struct is imported as tuple of 10 UInt8 items. There's a lot of examples on how to read values as swift string from that struct member, but I want to be able to set something in member?

```
struct CStrut {
char[10] item;
}
```

How can set value in item from swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `withUnsafeMutablePointer(_:_:)`:

```
var a = CStruct(item: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
var CStructPtr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&a.item) { (b) -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int8> in
    // UnsafeMutableBufferPointer is used because it a little more safe.
    return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(b), count: 10)
}

//Modify the tuple however you want
CStructPtr[0] = 42
CStructPtr[1] = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a syntax error in C:

```
struct CStruct {
    char item[10];
};
```

If you want to modify it in Swift:

```
var a = CStruct(item: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
a.item.0 = 42
a.item.1 = 30

print(a)
```

Comment: Well I do not want to copy items in the tuple one by one. I was hoping if there's a way to copy something like memcpy or something. There are other structs in my case which are like 32 unit long and it's not feasible to copy items in the tuple one by one.